# ASP.NET MVC with angular routing url issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular-routing

I have problem with angular routing and ASP.NET MVC. 
The problem is with URL.

MVC controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("BackOffice/Merchants")]
public class MerchantsController : Controller
{
    [Route("Add")]
    public ActionResult Add()
        => View("~/Views/BackOffice/Merchants/View.cshtml");
    [Route("{id}/Edit")]
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id) // e08c5580-29e3-4429-9c76-b1464f0365ae
        => View("~/Views/BackOffice/Merchants/View.cshtml");
}
```

Angular app.js

```
 var app = angular.module("backofficeMerchantsApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/",
        {
            template: "<h1>eee</h1>"
        })
        .when("/Add",
        {
            templateUrl: "add.html",
            controller: "addController"
        });
});
```

And there is problem:

When I enter:

```
.../BackOffice/Merchants/Add
```

The angular loads "/" page. 
When I enter:

```
.../BackOffice/Merchants/Add#/Add
```

The angular loads "/Add" page.

I don't want it. What I have done wrong?

I want to:

When I enter:

```
.../BackOffice/Merchants
```

The angular loads "/" page. 
When I enter:

```
.../BackOffice/Merchants/Add
```

The angular loads "/Add" page.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out here: [Angular Routing with ASP MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999803/angular-routing-with-asp-mvc/40000700#40000700)

Hope this helps if you are still having a hard time.